# Uninstall all installed gems, in OSX?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

There are instances where I would like to revert and uninstall all previous gem installations.

For instance, I needed to assist a friend migrate their rails development machine to use RVM.  As they had been previously using the system-wide `gem`, he was experiencing many headaches when working with multiple projects.  *Essentially, he was the poster-child for an RVM convert.*

How can I elegantly uninstall all of the gems on his OSX system?

Comment: Nowadays this is unnecessary. RVM knows where to look for the gems after you switch to the right Ruby version.

Comment: `yes Y | gem uninstall -a -I`

Comment: Just a quick note to @FranklinYu - this is not always the case. I've had instances where a globally installed copy of Nokogiri seemed to always be taking precedent over the RVM gemset, and the global one *had* to be uninstalled.

Comment: @NathanCrause Then it’s a bug in RVM and should be reported. I’m pretty sure this isn’t the intended behavior of RVM.

Comment: @FranklinYu you're right, but until such an issue is resolved, there would still be the need for a way to purge all gems. I was only referring to the point of it being "unnecessary", which would be true in an ideal situation, but hey, things go sideways all the time.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could also build out a new Gemfile and run `bundle clean --force`. This will remove all other gems that aren't included in the new Gemfile.

Comment: best answer because test-unit cannot be uninstalled and kills the process.

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer. I feel OP should choose this post 2.0.0.

Comment: This is certainly working for me and much more elegant than other versions

Comment: This is a great technique. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 471):

**Rubygems >= 2.1.0**

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

`a` removes all versions
`I` ignores dependencies
`x` includes executables

**Rubgems < 2.1.0**

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

Comment: Duh, you beat me to the speed :)

Comment: Then of course, you'll want to re-install a sane list of default gems which for me is: "gem install bundler json minitest rake rdoc"

Comment: gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | sudo xargs gem uninstall -Iax                   -worked for me

Comment: Does not work: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "test-unit" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem` (gem 2.0.3)

Comment: @Anthony Though this is a bit dangerous, you can suppress errors with `for i in \`gem list --no-versions\`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i 2>/dev/null; done`

Comment: Just added sudo `for i in `sudo gem list --no-versions`; do sudo gem uninstall -aIx $i; done`

Comment: Please mention `sudo` since OP mentioned system-wide `gem` in OS X.

Comment: Hey, I'm writing a guide on this topic. Has anyone on gem < 2.1.0 tried [this bash script](https://gist.github.com/stilist/256d6e1684f7e9d9f4e660655d1bab64) to work around the errors?

Answer (score 31):

A slighest different version, skipping the cut step, taking advantage of the '--no-version' option:

```
gem list --no-version |xargs gem uninstall -ax
```

Since you are removing everything, I don't see the need for the 'I' option. Whenever the gem is removed, it's fine.

Comment: `sudo` shouldn't be necessary if the gems were installed by an ordinary user.

Comment: See my answer for a reason why I downvoted. I wanted to comment here but comments do not allow lines...

Comment: good, can remove a lot of gems, but something dosen`t it like bundle, rake, rvm

Comment: Very elegant but fails due to the inability to remove default gems.  Suggest crftr's solution instead

Answer (score 14):

First make sure you have at least gem version 2.1.0

```
gem update --system
gem --version
# 2.6.4
```

To uninstall simply run:

```
gem uninstall --all
```

You may need to use the `sudo` command:

```
sudo gem uninstall --all
```

Answer (score 11):

Use either

```
$ gem list --no-version | xargs gem uninstall -ax
```

or

```
$ sudo gem list --no-version | xargs sudo gem uninstall -ax
```

Depending on what you want, you may need to execute both, because "gem list" and "sudo gem list" provide independent lists.

Do not mix a normal "gem list" with a sudo-ed "gem uninstall" nor the other way around otherwise you may end up uninstalling sudo-installed gems (former) or getting a lot of errors (latter).

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to exclude sudo. For both versions users can rely on your answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Rubygems version 2.1.0 or later, you can try: `gem uninstall --all`.

Comment: It should be 'gem' not 'gems'.

Answer (score 9):

Rubygems >= 2.1.0

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

If Terminal returns below error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Then write above command as below

```
sudo gem uninstall -aIx
```

And enter your mac os account password
Done!!

Comment: again same error after executing above command.

Answer (score 9):

And for those of you who are here because you want to remove all gems with a certain prefix (*ahem* I'm looking at you aws-sdk!) you can run something like this:

```
gem list --no-version | grep "aws-sdk-" | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

Obviously put in your query instead of `aws-sdk-`. You need the `-I` in there to ignore dependencies.

*Adopted form Ando's [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644170/2187161)*

Answer (score 7):

If you like doing it using ruby:

```
ruby -e "`gem list`.split(/$/).each { |line| puts `gem uninstall -Iax #{line.split(' ')[0]}` unless line.strip.empty? }"
```

Cheers

Comment: I am getting an error with this: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

Comment: @mbdev Fixed, hehe providing support to my answers on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: This is handy in that it works in Windows where the command shell is... not good.

Answer (score 5):

The only command helped me to cleanup all gems and ignores default gems, which can't be uninstalled

```
for x in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall $x -a -x -I; done
```

Answer (score 3):

I did that not too long ago (same poster-child RVM switcher situation):

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | sudo xargs gem uninstall -Iax
```

Takes the list of all gems (incl. version stuff), cuts it to keep only the gem name, then uninstalls all versions of such gems.

The `sudo` is only useful if you had gems installed system-wide, and should not be included unless necessary.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to remove gems installed as root, xargs seems to halt when it encounters an error trying to uninstall a default gem:

```
sudo gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
# ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
#    gem "test-unit" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

This won't work for everyone, but here's what I used instead:

```
sudo for gem (`gem list | cut -d" " -f1`); do gem uninstall $gem -aIx; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gem list --no-version | grep -v -e 'psych' -e 'rdoc' -e 'openssl' -e 'json' -e 'io-console' -e 'bigdecimal' | xargs sudo gem uninstall -ax
```

grep here is excluding default gems. All other gems will be uninstalled. You can also precede it with `sudo` in case you get permission issues.