# installing ruby and rails on OSX, after installing Ruby and Rubygems the "gem install rails" command doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im installing ruby on rails and i have ruby 1.9.2 installed as well as rubygems. im using rvm for ruby installation. anyways, when trying to install rails by typing "sudo gem install rails" I get:

"Successfully installed rails-3.2.3 1 gem installed Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.3... Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.3..."

but typing in "rails -v" gets:

"Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command"

what can I do?  everything else is up to date and working.  thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: http://railsoneclick.com/

Comment: i tried it but the application crashes immediately upon opening even after redownloading.

Comment: huh, works fine on my end, something is probably screwed up with your installation. Maybe try uninstalling all the gem's on your system (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx) and try again...